# How do I select Combobox value in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn

I've 3 columns in `DataGridView`.

1. TextType
2. Combobox
3. TextType

I've bind Combobox of Datagridview like this:

```
BindingSource bindingSourceUnit = new BindingSource();
bindingSourceUnit.DataSource = datatableObject;

ColumnUnit.DataSource = bindingSourceUnit;
ColumnUnit.ValueMember = "id";
ColumnUnit.DisplayMember = "title";
```

This is showing all items in each row of the ComboBox second column.
Now I'm fetching data from a database and I want to display it in the `DataGridView`.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Detail WHERE lr_id = @id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dgItem.Rows[0].Clone();
    row.Cells[dgItem.Columns["ColumnQty"].Index].Value = reader["qty"];
    row.Cells[dgItem.Columns["ColumnUnit"].Index].Value = reader["unit"];
    row.Cells[dgItem.Columns["ColumnDesc"].Index].Value = reader["detail"];
    dgItem.Rows.Add(row);
  }
}
```

In the while loop, "ColumnUnit" is my ComboboxType field. It's not allowing me to pre-select the value.

How can I set the value for this column?

Comment: have you used the debugger to step through the code and evaluate the value of row.. what are you cloning or trying to clone anyway..

Comment: I've saw in example, if you want to display data in grid either you have to clone row so it can have all columns or you have to manually add row with each time what type of data you have

Comment: you are getting the data from the select query.. once the query has been executed, return the data using the `Fill` method and bind the results to a datagrid via datatable or dataset..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Ajax combo box control or the standard check box list control?

In any case you need to tell the control which combo value should be selected, so you will have to do a check to see what the value is coming back from your database call and then search for that in the combo box list of values and when you find the correct value set the "selected" property to true

Try

```
row.Cells[dgItem.Columns["ColumnUnit"].Index].Selected = row.Cells[dgItem.Columns["ColumnUnit"].Index].Value == reader["unit"] ? true : false;
```

Try casting the cell into a DataGridViewComboBoxCell and you should be able to change the value that way.

```
var tempCombo = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)drNew.Cells[0].Value;
```

Comment: I'm using C# Windows Form, In combobox there will be Display & Value, so from database I'll get Value, based on value I would like to select combobox value

Comment: I've tried above code, neither selecting combobox value nor error.

Comment: Try - var tempCombo = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)drNew.Cells[0].Value; I've added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

A solution (perhaps not the best one):

```
private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender,
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["ColumnUnit"].Value = ... ; // set default value here
}
```